# How to find all targets with specific attribute in entire repository?

Tags: bazel

I'd like to find all build targets in the entire repository, which have the value `my-binary` in the attribute `tags`.

I have build targets with associated tags.

```
project.cc_binary(
  name = "MyBinary1",
  tags = ["my-binary", "another-cool-tag"],
  ...
)
```

I know how to list all targets in the repository.

```
bazel query 'project/...' --output package
```

I know how to find the targets for a specific package.

```
bazel query 'attr(tags, "my-binary", //path/to/package:*)
```

*But how to combine the two without a small Bash/Python script?*

Ideally, there was something like this.

```
bazel query 'attr(tags, "my-binary", //*:*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a solution.

```
bazel query 'attr(tags, "my-binary", //...:*)'
```

Comment: `//...:*` will match any target or any file in the repository. You can simplify with `//...` which matches any target in the repository.